# save radio button selection in post-meta on submit

Tags: metabox, save-post, post-meta

Right now I'm reading tags from the tag box, and putting them in a form with radio buttons so the user can choose a "main tag" from the tags they just typed in:

```
function write_tags(){
    var rawtags = $j(".tagchecklist").find("span").text(); 
    var stags = rawtags.split("X");
    var ftags = stags.slice(1);

    document.getElementById('tag_options').innerHTML = '';

    $j.each( ftags, function(i, l){
        $j("#tag_options").append('<input type="radio" name="mainTagButtons" value="' + i + '" /> '+ l +'<br />');
    });

}
```

Now that I have these displayed and selectable, I have no idea how to save the selection to post meta, or how to check the value there to see if it's saved. First I tried this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['mainTagButtons'])) {
  $this->data['mainTag'] = $_POST['mainTagButtons']; }


if ( isset($this->data) && $this->data != '' )
    update_post_meta($id, 'mainTag', $this->data);
```

But I'm not sure how to test to see if it worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
update_post_meta($id, 'main_tag', $_POST['mainTagButtons'])
```

Easy